# Need Context in WorkManager

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

I'm using `WorkManager 1.0.0-alpha05` to schedule some task to run in the feature that my app may or may not be running. The job I'm going to do requires `context` so how can I pass context to this?

```
class CompressWorker : Worker() {

    override fun doWork(): Result {
        //need context here
        Log.e("alz", "work manager runs")
        return Result.SUCCESS
    }
 }
```

And here is how I initialized the work.

```
val oneTimeWork = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<CompressWorker>()
        .setInitialDelay(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .build()

WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(oneTimeWork)
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It depends on what kind of `Context` do you need. According to [the documentation of the `Worker` class](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/Worker), you can simply call [`getApplicationContext()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/Worker.html#getApplicationContext()) method directly from the `Worker` class to get the `Context` of the entire application, which should be reasonable in this use case.

Comment: You can get context from the constructor of Worker class: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/Worker.html#Worker(android.content.Context,%20androidx.work.WorkerParameters)

Comment: So WorkManager can run jobs even with the app killed, exactly which app's context is returned here?

Comment: When app is killed, it should not work, but when app is running and you invoke WorkManager without Activity context, but with App context (e.g. from another place of the app), it should work.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation of the Worker class](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/Worker) does *not* mention that calling `getApplicationContext()` should be the preferred way of getting the `Context`. On the other hand, it does explicitly document that the public constructor of `Worker` takes a `Context` as the first parameter.

```
public Worker (Context context, 
            WorkerParameters workerParams)
```

So if you need a context in the `Worker` class, use the one from its construction.

Comment: It's the same thing actually! The context passed as an argument is what gets returned from `getApplicationContext()`. Refer the implementation of the `Worker` class!

Comment: If that's so, then what's the purpose of passing a context in through the Worker's constructor? It would seem that the purpose is for the logic in the Worker to use that context if needed?

Comment: You got that right! The worker object internally uses the context for its own purpose. There is hardly any android framework/library construct not needing the context object!

Comment: So if we're subclassing Worker, it seems reasonable to use that context object for our class too, doesn't it?

Comment: you are right @auspicious99, using getApplicationContext() in the worker class throws an exception in some cases. it is preferred to use context from the Worker's constructor.